Amazon AWS Bedrock : how to detect timeout?
I have a code like this:
$bedrockRuntimeClient = new BedrockRuntimeClient([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => $region, 
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => $accessKey,
            'secret' => $secretKey,
        ]
        
    ]);

.....

  $result = $bedrockRuntimeClient->invokeModel([
            'contentType' => 'application/json',
            'body' => json_encode($body),
            'modelId' => $modelId
        ]);

How to set a timeout on invokeModel so that I leave maximum X seconds to this function to execute, and if timeout is reached I want to be able to know it (to launch another function for example) ?
Or the timeout has to be set on $bedrockRuntimeClient ?
Thanks !

When dealing LLMs in Bedrock you can get a timeout, (which actually comes from the botocore client), the error message reads;
AWSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='bedrock-runtime.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60).
To change the timeout you need to access the advanced configuration for Botocore clients from botocore.config.
There are two timeouts you can use;

connect_timeout (float or int) – The time in seconds till a timeout exception is thrown when attempting to make a connection. The default is 60 seconds.
read_timeout (float or int) – The time in seconds till a timeout exception is thrown when attempting to read from a connection. The default is 60 seconds.

In python it looks like this (sorry, I'm not a PHP person);
from boto3 import client
from botocore.config import Config

config = Config(read_timeout=1000)

client = boto3.client(service_name='bedrock-runtime', 
                      region_name='us-east-1',
                      config=config)

As far as catching the time out, again I'm no PHP person but having had a scan of How to "catch" max execution time error in php it looks fairly straightforward.
References:
Error raised by bedrock service: Read timeout on endpoint URL
